# SQL get interection of values across multiple rows grouped by primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have table with data as follows

```
+----+------+
| id | code |
+----+------+
|  1 |  M   |
|  1 |  Y   |
|  2 |  M   |
|  2 |  S   |
|  3 |  M   |
|  3 |  Q   |
+----+------+
```

I would like to know if its possible to write a query that would return a list of codes that are unique to each ID? If there is no intersection the query should return no rows.

In the example above the only value common to all is M.

```
+----+------+
| id | code |
+----+------+
|  1 |  M   |
|  1 |  S   |
|  2 |  M   |
|  2 |  S   |
|  2 |  H   |
|  3 |  M   |
|  3 |  S   |
|  3 |  Q   |
+----+------+
```

The above would return M and S, common to all three ID's

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT code
FROM mytable
GROUP BY code
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM mytable)
```

The above query assumes that `code` can appear only *once* per `id`.

Comment: Thanks Giorgos, simple and effective.